# How access and edit svg nodes using PySide?

Tags: python, svg, pyside

I am using **PySide** to load an **svg** image into a Qt gui. The svg, made with inkscape, is composed by layers and elements (`rect`, `circle`, `path`, `g` groups...).

This is the code I am using:

```
from PySide import QtSvg                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
from PySide.QtCore import QLocale                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
from PySide.QtGui import *                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    import sys                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    svgWidget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget('file.svg')                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    svgWidget.show()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Once imported, is it possible to **access and edit/modify a specific node or element**, for example to modify a path or to change the color of a rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SVG is a XML file, you can open it with `QDomDocument` and edit it.

An example to change the color of the first path:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    doc = QDomDocument("doc")

    file = QFile("image.svg")
    if not file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
        print("Cannot open the file")
        exit(-1)

    if not doc.setContent(file):
        print("Cannot parse the content");
        file.close()
        exit(-1)
    file.close()

    roots = doc.elementsByTagName("svg")
    if roots.size() < 1:
       print("Cannot find root")
       exit(-1)

    # Change the color of the first path
    root = roots.at(0).toElement()
    path = root.firstChild().toElement()
    path.setAttribute("fill", "#FF0000")

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    svgWidget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget()
    svgWidget.load(doc.toByteArray())
    svgWidget.show()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Now I "just" have to learn how traversing the DOM and finding elements, as I used to do with other languages.